# Split JSON every N

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to separate a json into several pieces n times depending on the size of the json and the limit of characters within a field. For example, if the json occupies 16000 characters I divide it by 4000 (which is the limit per field) and thus divide it into 4 pieces type string[0], string[1],string[2],string[3] and then print them to the screen.

I have this code but it always gives me the following error:

> Error: Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length

```
var splitA = [];

function separatedFields(nCharacter, valueDeInfo) {
  var limit = 4000;
  var split = [];
  var nfield = Math.ceil((nCharacter) / limit);
  var begin = 0;
  var end = 4000;

  for (i = 0; i < nfield; i++) {
    if (i == nfield - 1) {
      split[i] = valueDeInfo.slice(begin, end);
      begin = end;
      end = nCharacter;
    } else {
      split[i] = valueDeInfo.slice(begin, end);
      begin = end;
      end = end + 4000;
    }
  }

  return split;
}

splitA = separatedFields(nCharacter, valueDeInfo);
Write("ARRAY FIRST 4000: " + splitA[0]);
```

Example of input/output:

```json
valueDeInfo = ['{"Status":"OK","RequestID":"e5517d4e-ee43-451a-bbe8-09f9fc714c21","Results":[{"CustomerKey":null,"Name":"Control","ObjectID":null,"FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"MaxLength":0,"Ordinal":3,"DefaultValue":"1","DataExtension":null,"StorageType":"Unspecified","DataType":null,"ValueType":"xsdstring","PropertyType":"string","IsCreatable":false,"IsUpdatable":false,"IsRetrievable":false,"IsQueryable":false,"IsFilterable":false,"IsPartnerProperty":false,"IsAccountProperty":false,"PartnerMap":null,"AttributeMaps":null,"Markups":null,"Precision":0,"Scale":0,"Label":null,"Description":null,"MinLength":0,"MinValue":null,"MaxValue":null,"IsRequired":false,"IsViewable":false,"IsEditable":false,"IsNillable":false,"IsRestrictedPicklist":false,"PicklistItems":null,"IsSendTime":false,"DisplayOrder":0,"References":null,"RelationshipName":null,"Status":null,"IsContextSpecific":false,"Client":null,"PartnerKey":null,"PartnerProperties":null,"CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","ModifiedDate":null,"ID":0,"Owner":null,"CorrelationID":null,"ObjectState":null,"IsPlatformObject":false}, {"CustomerKey":null,"Name":"CategoryID","ObjectID":null,"FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"MaxLength":0,"Ordinal":8,"DefaultValue":"","DataExtension":null,"StorageType":"Unspecified","DataType":null,"ValueType":"xsdstring","PropertyType":"string","IsCreatable":false,"IsUpdatable":false,"IsRetrievable":false,"IsQueryable":false,"IsFilterable":false,"IsPartnerProperty":false,"IsAccountProperty":false,"PartnerMap":null,"AttributeMaps":null,"Markups":null,"Precision":0,"Scale":0,"Label":null,"Description":null,"MinLength":0,"MinValue":null,"MaxValue":null,"IsRequired":false,"IsViewable":false,"IsEditable":false,"IsNillable":false,"IsRestrictedPicklist":false,"PicklistItems":null,"IsSendTime":false,"DisplayOrder":0,"References":null,"RelationshipName":null,"Status":null,"IsContextSpecific":false,"Client":null,"PartnerKey":null,"PartnerProperties":null,"CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","ModifiedDate":null,"ID":0,"Owner":null,"CorrelationID":null,"ObjectState":null,"IsPlatformObject":false}, {"CustomerKey":null,"Name":"IsSendable","ObjectID":null,"FieldType":"Boolean","IsPrimaryKey":false,"MaxLength":0,"Ordinal":2,"DefaultValue":"","DataExtension":null,"StorageType":"Unspecified","DataType":null,"ValueType":"xsdstring","PropertyType":"string","IsCreatable":false,"IsUpdatable":false,"IsRetrievable":false,"IsQueryable":false,"IsFilterable":false,"IsPartnerProperty":false,"IsAccountProperty":false,"PartnerMap":null,"AttributeMaps":null,"Markups":null,"Precision":0,"Scale":0,"Label":null,"Description":null,"MinLength":0,"MinValue":null,"MaxValue":null,"IsRequired":false,"IsViewable":false,"IsEditable":false,"IsNillable":false,"IsRestrictedPicklist":false,"PicklistItems":null,"IsSendTime":false,"DisplayOrder":0,"References":null,"RelationshipName":null,"Status":null,"IsContextSpecific":false,"Client":null,"PartnerKey":null,"PartnerProperties":null,"CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","ModifiedDate":null,"ID":0,"Owner":null,"CorrelationID":null,"ObjectState":null,"IsPlatformObject":false}, {"CustomerKey":null,"Name":"Name","ObjectID":null,"FieldType":"Text","IsPrimaryKey":true,"MaxLength":50,"Ordinal":0,"DefaultValue":"","DataExtension":null,"StorageType":"Unspecified","DataType":null,"ValueType":"xsdstring","PropertyType":"string","IsCreatable":false,"IsUpdatable":false,"IsRetrievable":false,"IsQueryable":false,"IsFilterable":false,"IsPartnerProperty":false,"IsAccountProperty":false,"PartnerMap":null,"AttributeMaps":null,"Markups":null,"Precision":0,"Scale":0,"Label":null,"Description":null,"MinLength":0,"MinValue":null,"MaxValue":null,"IsRequired":true,"IsViewable":false,"IsEditable":false,"IsNillable":false,"IsRestrictedPicklist":false,"PicklistItems":null,"IsSendTime":false,"DisplayOrder":0,"References":null,"RelationshipName":null,"Status":null,"IsContextSpecific":false,"Client":null,"PartnerKey":null,"PartnerProperties":null,"CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","ModifiedDate":null,"ID":0,"Owner":null,"CorrelationID":null,"ObjectState":null,"IsPlatformObject":false}, {"CustomerKey":null,"Name":"IsRequired","ObjectID":null,"FieldType":"Boolean","IsPrimaryKey":false,"MaxLength":0,"Ordinal":10,"DefaultValue":"","DataExtension":null,"StorageType":"Unspecified","DataType":null,"ValueType":"xsdstring","PropertyType":"string","IsCreatable":false,"IsUpdatable":false,"IsRetrievable":false,"IsQueryable":false,"IsFilterable":false,"IsPartnerProperty":false,"IsAccountProperty":false,"PartnerMap":null,"AttributeMaps":null,"Markups":null,"Precision":0,"Scale":0,"Label":null,"Description":null,"MinLength":0,"MinValue":null,"MaxValue":null,"IsRequired":false,"IsViewable":false,"IsEditable":false,"IsNillable":false,"IsRestrictedPicklist":false,"PicklistItems":null,"IsSendTime":false,"DisplayOrder":0,"References":null,"RelationshipName":null,"Status":null,"IsContextSpecific":false,"Client":null,"PartnerKey":null,"PartnerProperties":null,"CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","ModifiedDate":null,"ID":0,"Owner":null,"CorrelationID":null,"ObjectState":null,"IsPlatformObject":false}, {"CustomerKey":null,"Name":"infoDE3","ObjectID":null,"FieldType":"Text","IsPrimaryKey":false,"MaxLength":4000,"Ordinal":18,"DefaultValue":"","DataExtension":null,"StorageType":"Unspecified","DataType":null,"ValueType":"xsdstring","PropertyType":"string","IsCreatable":false,"IsUpdatable":false,"IsRetrievable":false,"IsQueryable":false,"IsFilterable":false,"IsPartnerProperty":false,"IsAccountProperty":false,"PartnerMap":null,"AttributeMaps":null,"Markups":null,"Precision":0,"Scale":0,"Label":null,"Description":null,"MinLength":0,"MinValue":null,"MaxValue":null,"IsRequired":true,"IsViewable":false,"IsEditable":false,"IsNillable":false,"IsRestrictedPicklist":false,"PicklistItems":null,"IsSendTime":false,"DisplayOrder":0,"References":null,"RelationshipName":null,"Status":null,"IsContextSpecific":false,"Client":null,"PartnerKey":null,"PartnerProperties":null,"CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","ModifiedDate":null,"ID":0,"Owner":null,"CorrelationID":null,"ObjectState":null,"IsPlatformObject":false}, {"CustomerKey":null,"Name":"Description","ObjectID":null,"FieldType":"Text","IsPrimaryKey":false,"MaxLength":4000,"Ordinal":6,"DefaultValue":"","DataExtension":null,"StorageType":"Unspecified","DataType":null,"ValueType":"xsdstring","PropertyType":"string","IsCreatable":false,"IsUpdatable":false,"IsRetrievable":false,"IsQueryable":false,"IsFilterable":false,"IsPartnerProperty":false,"IsAccountProperty":false,"PartnerMap":null,"AttributeMaps":null,"Markups":null,"Precision":0,"Scale":0,"Label":null,"Description":null,"MinLength":0,"MinValue":null,"MaxValue":null,"IsRequired":false,"IsViewable":false,"IsEditable":false,"IsNillable":false,"IsRestrictedPicklist":false,"PicklistItems":null,"IsSendTime":false,"DisplayOrder":0,"References":null,"RelationshipName":null,"Status":null,"IsContextSpecific":false,"Client":null,"PartnerKey":null,"PartnerProperties":null,"CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","ModifiedDate":null,"ID":0,"Owner":null,"CorrelationID":null,"ObjectState":null,"IsPlatformObject":false}, {"CustomerKey":null,"Name":"ModifiedDate","ObjectID":null,"FieldType":"Date","IsPrimaryKey":false,"MaxLength":0,"Ordinal":7,"DefaultValue":"","DataExtension":null,"StorageType":"Unspecified","DataType":null,"ValueType":"xsdstring","PropertyType":"string","IsCreatable":false,"IsUpdatable":false,"IsRetrievable":false,"IsQueryable":false,"IsFilterable":false,"IsPartnerProperty":false,"IsAccountProperty":false,"PartnerMap":null,"AttributeMaps":null,"Markups":null,"Precision":0,"Scale":0,"Label":null,"Description":null,"MinLength":0,"MinValue":null,"MaxValue":null,"IsRequired":false,"IsViewable":false,"IsEditable":false,"IsNillable":false,"IsRestrictedPicklist":false,"PicklistItems":null,"IsSendTime":false,"DisplayOrder":0,"References":null,"RelationshipName":null,"Status":null,"IsContextSpecific":false,"Client":null,"PartnerKey":null,"PartnerProperties":null,"CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","ModifiedDate":null,"ID":0,"Owner":null,"CorrelationID":null,"ObjectState":null,"IsPlatformObject":false}']
nCharacters = valueDeinfo.length;
```

The correct output would be:

```json
{"Status":"OK","RequestID":"e5517d4e-ee43-451a-bbe8-09f9fc714c21","Results":[{"CustomerKey":null,"Name":"Control","ObjectID":null,"FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"MaxLength":0,"Ordinal":3,"DefaultValue":"1","DataExtension":null,"StorageType":"Unspecified","DataType":null,"ValueType":"xsdstring","PropertyType":"string","IsCreatable":false,"IsUpdatable":false,"IsRetrievable":false,"IsQueryable":false,"IsFilterable":false,"IsPartnerProperty":false,"IsAccountProperty":false,"PartnerMap":null,"AttributeMaps":null,"Markups":null,"Precision":0,"Scale":0,"Label":null,"Description":null,"MinLength":0,"MinValue":null,"MaxValue":null,"IsRequired":false,"IsViewable":false,"IsEditable":false,"IsNillable":false,"IsRestrictedPicklist":false,"PicklistItems":null,"IsSendTime":false,"DisplayOrder":0,"References":null,"RelationshipName":null,"Status":null,"IsContextSpecific":false,"Client":null,"PartnerKey":null,"PartnerProperties":null,"CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","ModifiedDate":null,"ID":0,"Owner":null,"CorrelationID":null,"ObjectState":null,"IsPlatformObject":false}, {"CustomerKey":null,"Name":"CategoryID","ObjectID":null,"FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"MaxLength":0,"Ordinal":8,"DefaultValue":"","DataExtension":null,"StorageType":"Unspecified","DataType":null,"ValueType":"xsdstring","PropertyType":"string","IsCreatable":false,"IsUpdatable":false,"IsRetrievable":false,"IsQueryable":false,"IsFilterable":false,"IsPartnerProperty":false,"IsAccountProperty":false,"PartnerMap":null,"AttributeMaps":null,"Markups":null,"Precision":0,"Scale":0,"Label":null,"Description":null,"MinLength":0,"MinValue":null,"MaxValue":null,"IsRequired":false,"IsViewable":false,"IsEditable":false,"IsNillable":false,"IsRestrictedPicklist":false,"PicklistItems":null,"IsSendTime":false,"DisplayOrder":0,"References":null,"RelationshipName":null,"Status":null,"IsContextSpecific":false,"Client":null,"PartnerKey":null,"PartnerProperties":null,"CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","ModifiedDate":null,"ID":0,"Owner":null,"CorrelationID":null,"ObjectState":null,"IsPlatformObject":false}, {"CustomerKey":null,"Name":"IsSendable","ObjectID":null,"FieldType":"Boolean","IsPrimaryKey":false,"MaxLength":0,"Ordinal":2,"DefaultValue":"","DataExtension":null,"StorageType":"Unspecified","DataType":null,"ValueType":"xsdstring","PropertyType":"string","IsCreatable":false,"IsUpdatable":false,"IsRetrievable":false,"IsQueryable":false,"IsFilterable":false,"IsPartnerProperty":false,"IsAccountProperty":false,"PartnerMap":null,"AttributeMaps":null,"Markups":null,"Precision":0,"Scale":0,"Label":null,"Description":null,"MinLength":0,"MinValue":null,"MaxValue":null,"IsRequired":false,"IsViewable":false,"IsEditable":false,"IsNillable":false,"IsRestrictedPicklist":false,"PicklistItems":null,"IsSendTime":false,"DisplayOrder":0,"References":null,"RelationshipName":null,"Status":null,"IsContextSpecific":false,"Client":null,"PartnerKey":null,"PartnerProperties":null,"CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","ModifiedDate":null,"ID":0,"Owner":null,"CorrelationID":null,"ObjectState":null,"IsPlatformObject":false}, {"CustomerKey":null,"Name":"Name","ObjectID":null,"FieldType":"Text","IsPrimaryKey":true,"MaxLength":50,"Ordinal":0,"DefaultValue":"","DataExtension":null,"StorageType":"Unspecified","DataType":null,"ValueType":"xsdstring","PropertyType":"string","IsCreatable":false,"IsUpdatable":false,"IsRetrievable":false,"IsQueryable":false,"IsFilterable":false,"IsPartnerProperty":false,"IsAccountProperty":false,"PartnerMap":null,"AttributeMaps":null,"Markups":null,"Precision":0,"Scale":0,"Label":null,"Description":null,"MinLength":0,"MinValue":null,"MaxValue":null,"IsRequired":true,"IsViewable":false,"IsEditable":false,"IsNillable":false,"IsRestrictedPicklist":false,"PicklistItems":null,"IsSendTime":false,"DisplayOrder":0,"References":null,"RelationshipName":null,"Status":null,"IsContextSpecific":false,"Client":null,"PartnerKey":null,"PartnerProperties":null,"CreatedDate":"0001-01-0
```

Basically, in `splitA[0]` should be the first 4000 characters, in `split[1]` should be in the next 4000 characters and so on until you reach nCharacters

Comment: You can't arbitrarily cut JSON into pieces. Each piece still needs to be valid otherwise it will not parse

Comment: Even if i try with a normal Array of characters (not a json) i always result the same error…

Comment: What is `nCharacter` and `valueDeInfo` values?

Comment: Ncharacter is the length of my array and valueDeInfo is the array

Comment: Please add some sample inputs/outputs and the desired output?

Comment: I don't understand the output. It ends with `"0001-01-0` meaning it's incomplete and will not be parse-able.

Comment: It's true, sorry, I copied and pasted without paying attention to it. imagine that the output is parseable

Answer (score 0):

So you basically just want to split a string at a given number of characters?

You can try a regex for that

```js
const splitAtInterval = (string, interval) => {
  const r = new RegExp(`.{1,${interval}}`, 'g')
  return string.match(r);
}

var text = "Some random string (in your case your JSON string)";
console.log(splitAtInterval(text, 4));
```

There are other options, just search google for "split string after x characters". for example https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-split-string-substrings-n-characters

---

Obviously, as mentioned in the comments, those strings will not be valid json anymore. You will have to fetch all the entries again and connect them via `join`.